# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out

Tags: spring, tomcat7

I am using Spring JdbcTemplate class for performing database operations. My server is Tomcat 7.

When I click the button of my application to perform some DB operations I get the following error

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [XXXXX (my query) ]; 
**IO Error: Socket read timed out; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out**

**Strange Behaviour:-** This is happening only for the very first time. When I click the button next time everything is fine.

I even tried accessing the DB directly from toad and I am not getting any connection time out there.

DB Properties in context.xml:-

Resource name="jdbc/dsStaloneTelefoni"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@someIP:XXXXX"
              username="XXXX"
              password="XXXXXXXXXX"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              testOnReturn="true"
              validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
              maxActive="20"
              maxIdle="30"
              maxWait="-1"/>

Please help.